# How to extract 'numbers in word form' from a string

Tags: regex, nlp

Has anyone any idea where to start?
For example, extract "two" from "I have two apples". 
I'm looking in the direction of NLP or QDA. Any leads for how to go about it would be appreciated.

Comment: How about having a look-up table where ['one':1,'two':2,'three':3,...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in Stanford NER system.
It identifies numeric entities.

You can try it here: http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/corenlp/

Comment: Almost exactly what I was looking for. This is a real treat :) Thanks a million.

Comment: I think you might want to use the Stanford RegexNER tool (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner/). The standard Stanford NER models don't contain the NUM class, despite what is displayed in the NER output within the CoreNLP web demo.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
(((?:sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|fourteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fourteen|fifteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion|and)[,   -]*)+)
```

The words have to be out of order because regex matches the first alternation found. sixty needs to come before six, fourteen before four, etc.

**Demo:** [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3a672)

This regex may work better, it managers it ignore the trailing space

```
((\b(?:fourty|sixty|seventy|eighty|ninety|fourteen|sixteen|seventeen|eighteen|nineteen|one|two|three|four|five|six|seven|eight|nine|ten|eleven|twelve|thirteen|fifteen|twenty|thirty|forty|fifty|hundred|thousand|million|billion|trillion|and)\b[ ,    -]*)+(?=\W|$)+)
```

Also, you'll notice fourty at the begininning of this regex. It's a really common misspelling of forty, so I thought that might be useful to you. You can remove it if you like.